# Bootstrap carousel : add a class to body on slide change

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

when a slide changes, I'd like to add a class to the body.
Let's say I have 2 slides, when slide 1 is active it adds a class "slide1" the the body. When number 2 is active, it removes "slide1" from body and adds "slide2" instead. I don't have particular code since I'm using the basic Bootstrap markup for a carousel. Thanks in advance.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       This is slide 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        This is slide 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "to the body"? Literally the body tag or `<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">` or `<div class="item active">` or something else?

Comment: I mean the <body> tag of the page. Sorry it wasn't specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an event in bootstrap, for carousel, when slide transition is done:
`slid.bs.carousel`. Reference is [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel).

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gw5csb3z/). (Exactly the same code is fully working on my localhost, I do not understand why, but on jsfiddle there is some error with the value of next)

So, when a transition is down, you just need to remove the previous class from body, and add active.

Remove the `slide0` from the markers, because there are 2 sliders only, and add an init class `slide1` to your body.

Then here you go:

```
$(function () {
    var active = '';
    var next = null;
    $('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
        $('.carousel-indicators li').each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                active = $(this).data('slide-to');
                console.log(active);
                next = $(this).next('li').data('slide-to');
            }
        });
        $('body').removeClass('slide' + active);
        if (typeof next === 'undefined') {
            $('body').addClass('slide1');
        } else {
            $('body').addClass('slide' + next);
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" id="firstOl" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" id="secondOl"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" id="thirdOl"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       This is slide 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        This is slide 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#carousel-example-generic').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    console.log('slide event!');
if($('.firstOl').hasClass('active')){
$('body').addClass('slide1')
}else if($('.secondOl').hasClass('active')){
$('body').addClass('slide2')
}else if($('.thirdOl').hasClass('active')){
$('body').addClass('slide3')
}
});
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used:

1. [the `slid.bs.carousel` event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events)

   > This event is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition.
2. [the `.addClass()` method](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

   > Adds the specified class(es) to each element in the set of matched elements.
3. [the `.removeClass()` method](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

   > Remove a single class, multiple classes, or all classes from each element in the set of matched elements.

Please check the result. Is it what you want to achieve?

```js
var selectBody = $( 'body' );
var curId = 0;
selectBody.addClass( 'slide-' + curId );

$( '#carousel-example-generic' ).on( 'slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    var newId = $( this ).find( 'li.active' ).attr( 'data-slide-to' );
    if ( newId != curId ) {
      selectBody.removeClass( 'slide-' + curId ).addClass( 'slide-' + newId );
      curId = newId;
    }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body { padding: 20px 80px; }
.carousel-inner img { width: 100%; }
.slide-0 { background: #f9c; }
.slide-1 { background: #cf9; }
.slide-2 { background: #9cf; }
```

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="//placehold.it/900x300/c69/fff/?text=Slide%200">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/900x300/9c6/fff/?text=Slide%201">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/900x300/69c/fff/?text=Slide%202">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```